# How widely were Ramadan observed among Muslim slaves in pre-civil war America?

Tags: united-states, slavery, muslims

[Muslims made up an estimated 15%-30% of Africans enslaved in the United States before the civil war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islam_in_the_United_States#Slaves). Is there a general sense of how widely the fast of [Ramadan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramadan) was observed among them? There were obviously practical difficulties, for example fasting while carrying out forced physical work, or maybe interference from their American masters on the religious practice.

Comment: From your link, the percentages presented as estimates and your use of the term "significant proportion" Do Not Match.  Please revise your language to a term like "some" or a small percentage, since that is what your source presents. (A fifth to a sixth, it appears from your source).

Comment: Likely relevant: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2211064?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: Additionally: https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=HnIPyaRRYsYC&oi=fnd&pg=PA77&dq=ramadan+louisiana+18th+century&ots=5uTHVB_r4N&sig=Mz5DrJ19-UyZUr7NKVc1GyVhNMY#v=onepage&q=ramadan&f=false

Answer (score 4):

One of the main cod-justifications for slavery was to convert the slaves to Christianity: they called slavery 'opening the gates of mercy'. It's doubtful that any Muslim slaves were allowed to remain Muslim. There were very few black Muslims in America until the nation of Islam was founded, and its members were sui generis converts.

Comment: This does not answer his question.  The question has to do with those who celebrated Ramadan, etc: if there is a record of that, it may answer the question.  Your last sentence is correct, but about four generations removed.

Comment: The answer is that if slaves were Muslim when they arrived, they didn't remain practising Muslims for long, nor would their children have been allowed to be Muslims. So, no Ramadan.

Comment: Do you have supporting evidence beyond speculation?

Comment: Slaves were forcefully converted to Christianity. I don't need to reference that, it's common knowledge, no less than that the first world war started in 1914.

Comment: You are invited to read up on how ["common knowledge"](http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/a/623/16773) isn't a valid argument on History.SE.

Comment: Oh for heaven's sake. If you don't believe me that there were forced conversions to Christianity, read books about slavery, or if that's too inconvenient read Wikipedia. I found a well-cited Wikipedia article saying that they were forcefully converted. Believe me, it's not that hard.

Comment: I asked you for a source, and all I got was an argument.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islam_in_the_United_States. There it is, in the lead. I didn't link it before because I thought it would be easy to check with minimal effort.